# How to UPDATE single column with returned data in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Given the output of a SELECT statement below, how would I update all records' "CameraLocationID" field to the value in the "LocationID" field?

**Current State:**

```
ItemID  CameraID    CameraLocationID    LocationID
2       23038       NULL                335
3       23039       NULL                67
4       23040       NULL                34
5       23041       NULL                234
```

**Desired Output:**

```
ItemID  CameraID    CameraLocationID    LocationID
2       23038       335                 335
3       23039       67                  67
4       23040       34                  34
5       23041       234                 234
```

What I've tried:

- Selecting, and then trying to copy/paste single column using SSMS
- An INSERT INTO (knowing pretty much this wouldn't work as I'm not really "INSERTING" per se
- Copy and pasting the LocationID values into Excel, and then trying to c/p back into SQL using SSMS

Is there a SQL way of doing this fairly quickly?

EDIT: For future travelers, CameraLocationID and LocationID are in different tables. The SELECT brings them together into a single output before applying the UPDATE.

Comment: Could you provide your tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Update myTable set CameraLocationID = LocationID;
```

is all you need.

If locationID is coming from a different table you need an ID field there for linking, and I think the source and target both have CameraId field:

```
Update targetTable
set CameraLocationId = sourceTable.LocationId
from sourceTable 
where targetTable.CameraID = sourceTable.CameraID;
```

If that is not the case, please supply full information on table structures and current data.

Comment: That makes sense - let me try that and report back!

Comment: @SourceMatters, BTW you could also write your current "select" giving that result within parentheses like "... from (your select) sourceTable ..." too if need be.

Comment: Success! Much appreciated. Will add this to my personal cheat sheet.